# VBA application.ontime is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to achieve recursive functionality in macro using a code similar to this -:

```
    Dim showTime As Boolean

    Sub RunClock()
     Range("A1", "A1").Value = Now
     If showTime = True Then
     Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "RunClock"
     End If
    End Sub

Sub StartClock()
showTime = True
RunClock
End Sub

Sub StopClock()
showTime = False
End Sub
```

When I execute StartClock it shows time once then gives error - "Cannot run the macro 'Book1.RunClock'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: Is your code in a regular module?

Comment: What is regular mode ?

Comment: Not a worksheet code module or the `ThisWorkbook` module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to prefix sheet name along with macro name. Excel might me be looking in whole work book with name like Sheet1.RunClock, so try as below (assuming the macro is in Sheet1)

```
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "!Sheet1.RunClock"
```